# How to interact two variables in python?

Tags: python, statistics, data, feature-engineering, data-science-model

I have about 8 features as my predictors in a logistic model I am trying to fit in python. One of the features is TotalAward (Financial Aid) and the second is NEED. I am attempting to predict the likelihood of student retention (not leaving/transferring). Since the feature (NEED) affects the relationship between TotalAward and Retention (y=1), I would like to interact it without interacting any other features in my (`X=df[[ 'x1', 'x2', etc]]`).  In other statistical software, like stata, you would simply do $X1*X2$. How can I do this in python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with pandas, you can simply multiply the two variables:

```
df['c'] = df.a * df.b
```

Other sklearn solutions are a little daunting. But with pasty, you can construct design matrixes.

https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html

E.g. `X, y = dmatrices('y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x1:x2', df)`

Comment: Thank you. I assume that the first solution is for two continuous variables. How would you interact a categorical (or binary) with a continuous variable.